# Passing custom types by reference — any performance benefit?

Tags: c++, performance, parameters, reference

Is there any difference in compiled code in:

```
point operator-(point const&a,point const&b)
```

versus

```
point operator-(point a,point b)
```

?
where `point` is a custom structure?

Comment: Yep...the first is call by reference, the second call by value.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume so. `point operator-(point const&a,point const&b)` is better for 2 reasons: passing by reference means that you can avoid the overhead of recopying an object. The other is the fact that it takes a reference to `const`, which means both `const` and nonconst versions of `point` can use this function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Using the first method a copy of `a` and `b` is made and passed to the function. which can be costly if `Point` is a big `class` or `struct`.

The benefit of having `const` with passing by reference is

- You can use the method on `const` objects since you have prevented modification to the variables
- You can pass a temporary to the function safely.

Answer (score 0):

This will largely depend on the complexity of the constructor and size of the object.

If we have:

```
class point
{
    int x;
    int y;
   public:
    point(int ax, int ay) : x(ax), y(ay) { }
};
```

then the benefit is very small, if any (because the usage inside `operator-` will be more complex.

On the other hand, if `point` is:

```
class point
{
    BigInt<200> x;
    BigInt<200> y;
   public:
    point(int ax, int ay) : x(ax), y(ay) { }
};
```

where `BigInt` is a 200 byte array for "big number" calculations, because you are simulating the entire universe in the unit of femtometers. Then of course the effort of copying the 200 * 2 bytes * 2 objects makes for a lot of copying, and not a good idea to pass by value.

Same applies if creating/destroying the `point` object is complicated (if the constructor is for example allocating memory...).

But like I hinted at above, it depends on the usage in the `operator-` too - if there are lots of accesses that has to be done on the reference, it can slow things down vs. a direct copy on the argument stack.